# Using ViewStub with Tabs in Android Layout

Tags: android, layout, stub

I have read http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html which explains how to use a viewstub as a lazy include for layouts.

This works fine on a simple list view i have, but **when I try to use it in my actual Tabbed layout, it disappears as soon as the tab gets any real content.**

I have set all tabs, and tab host to use wrap_content as height (so as not to push the stub off)

Has anyone used stubs with a tabbed view? What is the trick?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/discqueue" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/instantqueue"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </FrameLayout>
   <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub_navigate"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_navigate" android:layout="@layout/pagination_bar"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
  </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the lists too - If I limit the # of items to 5 or so, the navigation bar remains, once it goes above that it gets pushed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

The trick they don't mention on the developer site is that for list/grid type dynamic views you actually want to merge an existing view with any stubs, rather than inserting stubs into your view, like so;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include android:id="@+id/cell3" layout="@layout/queue_man" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_navigation"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_navigation"

        android:layout="@layout/pagination_bar"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</merge>
```

This of course leaves cupcake and donut users in the dust though.

Comment: Can you please explain this furthur?

Comment: Sweety - the code in my answer merges the orginal layout in my question with a new view (viewstub) defined in the new layout. So 2 files (the tabbed view with inner content only) and the merge file (that introduced stub to go below tabs).  And in your code you call the merged layout.